# If $B_d(x,r) \cap S \neq \emptyset $ for all $ r > 0$, then a sequence in $S$ goes to $x$.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Proposition: Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space, and $S$ a subset of $X$. If $B_d(x, r) \cap S \neq \emptyset$ for all $r >0$, then there is a sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty} \subset S$ such that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n = x$.

My “proof” relies on the assumption that for every real $\epsilon > 0$ we can find some positive integer $n$ large enough that $\frac{1}{n} < \epsilon$. So (1) is this true and (2) does the following proof make any sense? I’m kind of confused about the behavior of irrational numbers near 0, and it is not immediately clear to me that I can always choose a rational number closer to zero than an irrational.

Proof: For any positive integer $n$ we already know that $B_d(x, \frac{1}{n}) \cap S \neq \emptyset$, so for any such $n$ we can define $x_n$ to be some element of both $B_d(x, \frac{1}{n})$ and $S$. For every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists some $a > 0$ such that $\frac{1}{a} < \epsilon$. For every $n > a$, we have $d(x, x_n) < \frac{1}{n} < \frac{1}{a} < \epsilon$, so $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n = x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a fundamental property of $\Bbb R$ (as an ordered field) called the [Archimedean property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_property). Given that fact, your proof makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** This follows immediately from the archimedian property. Indeed
$$\frac{1}{n} < \epsilon \Leftrightarrow n > \frac{1}{\epsilon}$$
and such $n$ exists by the archimedian property. This $n$ is usually denoted by $\lfloor \frac{1}{\epsilon}\rfloor +1$.